# how to select data from mysql data base for current date and tommorrows date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database i want to select data from data base of current date only and after that for tommorrows date

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT      PatientMaster.PatientFirstName,PatientMaster.PatientLastName,PatientMaster.PatientID,ProviderAppointmentListings.ProviderNPI,ProviderAppointmentListings.AppointmentTime,ProviderAppointmentListings.AppointmentListingsID, '' FROM PatientMaster JOIN ProviderAppointmentListings ON PatientMaster.PatientID = ProviderAppointmentListings.PatientId LIMIT 0, 30");



$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here.  Please state the question more clearly.

Comment: do you mean between current date and tomorrows date?

Comment: mean in one querry i want for current date and in other i want for tommorrows date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE YOUR_DATE_FIELD=CURDATE() or YOUR_DATE_FIELD=CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE TO_DAYS(columnname) between TO_DAYS(NOW()) and TO_DAYS(NOW())+1